# UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 mapping / lossless conversion libraries in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need to perform a conversion of characters from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 in Java without losing for example all of the UTF-8 specific punctuation.
Ideally would like these to be converted to equivalents in ISO (e.g. there are probably 5 different single quotes in UTF-8 and would like them all converted to ISO single quote character).

String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") just won't do the trick in this case as it will lose the UTF-8-specific chars.

Do you know of any ready mappings or libraries in Java that would map UTF-8 specific characters to ISO?

Comment: you should be careful with your terminology: lossless conversion between UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 is impossible as the latter can't encode all of unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM's [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) project might be what you're looking for. It has support for fallback conversions.

Comment: Good idea, but their database does not contain too many fallbacks.
Ended up constructing my own one based on the UTF-8 data my system's processing. Surprisingly there weren't that many mappings necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using an OutputStream with an explicit character set of ISO-8859-1?

Then just write your Unicode chars and see what you get.

Comment: It will do the same thing as String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")

What I need is some kind of UTF to ISO (or even ASCII) normalization tool.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Development Kit has a tool called native2ascii that will do this. Use:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 [ inputfile [ outputfile ] ]
```

You can also go back the other way using the -reverse option.

Also see the [list of supported encodings for JDK 1.6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html).